# What is the type of XQuery passed to SQL Server XML Data Type methods?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

According to BOL on [value() Method (xml Data Type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx),

`value()` method takes two arguments

- XQuery
- SQLType

Do I need to pass `varchar` or `nvarchar` to `value()`?
How can I find out what kind of type XQuery or SQLType expects?

**End Goal**: To create utility UDF/sprocs that uses [XML Data Type methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with both:

```
WITH    q AS
        (
        SELECT  CAST('<root><node>1</node></root>' AS XML) AS doc
        )
SELECT  doc.value('(/root/node)[1]', 'INT'),
        doc.value(N'(/root/node)[1]', 'INT')
FROM    q
```

Note that the `XQuery` is compiled during the parsing stage, i. e. you can supply only the string literal as first argument (not a column, expression or a variable).

This string literal has no "type", since type assumes a set of possible values that are known only at runtime, and `XML` functions accept only literal `XQuery` expressions which should be known at compile time.

You cannot pass them from the arguments or your functions or as variables, you can only hardcode them into the query.

Treat them as reserved words (like `SELECT` or `UPDATE`), which for some reason should be enclosed into single quotes.

You should build the whole query dynamically if you want the `XQuery` to be dynamic.

Comment: I am quite shocked that I cannot pass an XQuery value as a parameter but only as a 'string literal'...

Comment: @Sung Meister: they don't expect "type", they expect a set of reserved words enclosed into single quotes, optionally prepended with `N`. Don't be fooled by the fact that it looks like a `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR`: it is neither of them.

Comment: It looks like BOL is quite misleading on XQuery parameter description - "Is a string , an XQuery expression...".  They don't mention anything about XML Data methods expecting "a set of reserved words enclosed into single quotes"

Comment: @Sung Meister: From the link you provided: *`XQuery`: is the `XQuery` expression, a string literal, that retrieves data inside the `XML` instance*. They state that it should be a literal, and the error message states the same.

Comment: Maybe I was lacking knowledge on "string literal" meant.  Thank you for clearing that confusion for me.